Light fixture with 4 sets of wires
I am replacing lights in our house, most of which are straightforward.  Lights being mounted have typical black/white/earth connections.
Then I ran into this one.  Part of the problem was the old light was mounted physically oddly, with the bracket that screws into the 2 screw holes you can see in the picture was mounted upside down, with the earth screw going upwards instead of down, and the twist connectors were up above that bar too.  So one twist connector I was able to pull down and unscrew it normally, the other when I pulled it just fell out... and I don't know where from.
There are 4 sets of black/white/earth wires into this fixture.  One black wire is out by itself, that was definitely attached to the old light fixture.  3 whites are tied together, and the remaining 3 blacks and 1 white are tied together.
I assume the separate black wire is going to the switch (only on the reasonining that its differently wired than the rest, which presumably go to the breaker then feed off to 2 other light fixtures?), and so I should tie the black wire of the light to this and the white wire of the light to the bundle of 3 whites?  But equally scared to just try it like this without being certain.  So any advice would be welcome, many thanks.


Since you have a white wire tied in with the blacks, there is almost certainly a switch loop on that cable. Connecting the light fixture to the bundle of white wires and the black return from the (probable) switch loop is a very reasonable guess. Since there's a light fixture in the middle, you won't create a dead short, meaning the three possibilities are: the light is stuck on, the light is stuck off, or the light works perfectly. With the likely switch loop, it's a strong possibility that it will just work.
